# I need to split date time into two columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I tried a couple of codes but failed. I checked the youtube to understand it but did not succeed. The youtube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Phib0IUNdg8

I looked into R for the data science book under the Dates and Time page. I have used as. date() function it didn't work. I tried to separate () too but no result. I am missing a concept please let me know.

Please help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41uma.jpg)

Comment: You haven't supplied enough information for people to help you. Please do not use images, and provide enough sample data and code for people to help you.   Overall, though, try using the lubridate package.   Finally, note that you have gotten very specific error messages that you should read and address.

Comment: Hello Stefan, I want to separate the DateTime column (started_at & ended-at) into the date column and time column. I was searching for the method on youtube and in the books like R for Data Science, and R Programming for Data Science. I didn't find any appropriate solution in them.

Comment: I have tried separate (), split(), as.Date(), and so on. Kindly let me know the solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to first make sure your data is known to be a date (not just a string).  The use the functions from lubridate to split them.  Please at least show an example of your string. No one can help otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The `lubridate` and `hms` packages allow extraction of dates and times.

An example:

```
date_time_text <- c("2023-04-28 18:04:02")

date_time <- lubridate::ymd_hms(date_time_text)
  date <- as.Date(date_time)
  time <- hms::as_hms(date_time)
```

Comment: Thank you Tech for your response. How do we use these functions with a large dataset? My dataset has 13 columns and 4 million rows. Kindly let me know the codes.

Comment: It should not be a problem even with 4 million rows.  Though, for a solution, you'd need to provide a sample of the data.  Assuming you have read the data into R use the `dput()` command to extract a sample and post it into your question.

Comment: Hello there, When it comes to a large dataset like 5 million rows, Do I need to copy all the dates and times and paste them in c("2023-04-28 18:04:02", "2023-04-19 11:29:02"..........). It doesn't sound right. What am I missing here?

Comment: Large data sets present some challenges with regard to memory - Have a look at this https://hbs-rcs.github.io/large_data_in_R/.  I'm not able to advise on this.